# How to create a product type extends simple product type

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create a product with delivery date and number of days custom options by default. for this i need one product type. so please create one product type for me and also i don't know how to create product type in magento. because I'm new to it

Answer (score 0):

you can create new product type via adding below code in your Modules `config.xml` file

```
<global>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <excellence translate="label" module="excellence_test">
                    <label>Excellence Product</label>
                    <model>excellence_test/product_type</model>
                    <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    <composite>0</composite>
                    <can_use_qty_decimals>1</can_use_qty_decimals>
                    <price_model>excellence_test/product_price</price_model>
                    <index_data_retreiver>excellence_test/catalogIndex_data_test</index_data_retreiver>
                    <price_indexer>excellence_test/indexer_price</price_indexer>
                </excellence>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
</global>
```

Also please reffer this url they have ready made extension for you .

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/06/17/create-custom-product-types/

Comment: not working well..   show some error  duplicate voilence in  file   (app/code/local/Excellence/Test/sql/excellence_test_setup/install-1.0.0.php)